# XML to HTML over xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to generate a table in my HTML for all 7 options in my XML.

I guess it works with `<xsl:for-each>` but I don't get it right, it only displays the same things.

Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="adressbuch.xsl"?>

<ADRESSBUCH>
    <PERSON KATEGORIE="Privat">
        <ANREDE TITEL="Herr"/>
        <VOLLER_NAME>
            <NAME>Müller</NAME>
            <VORNAME>Hans</VORNAME>
            <MITTELNAME>Peter</MITTELNAME>
            <SPITZNAME>meier</SPITZNAME>
        </VOLLER_NAME>
        <GEBURTSTAG DATUM="12.04.1965"/>
        <BERUF BEZEICHNUNG="Lehrer"/>
        <ADRESSE>
            <ADRESSE_PRIVAT>
                <STRASSE>Hinterberg 4</STRASSE>
                <POSTFACH>357</POSTFACH>
                <POSTLEITZAHL>56070</POSTLEITZAHL>
                <ORT>Koblenz</ORT>
                <REGION>Rheinland</REGION>
                <LAND>Deutschland</LAND>
            </ADRESSE_PRIVAT>
            <ADRESSE_GESCHAEFT>
                <FIRMA>Muster AG</FIRMA>
                <STRASSE>Vordemberg 8</STRASSE>
                <POSTFACH>456</POSTFACH>
                <POSTLEITZAHL>56098</POSTLEITZAHL>
                <ORT>Koblenz</ORT>
                <REGION>Rheinland</REGION>
                <LAND>Deutschland</LAND>
                <HOMEPAGE>http://www.musterag.de</HOMEPAGE>
            </ADRESSE_GESCHAEFT>
        </ADRESSE>
        <KONTAKT>
            <TELEFON>
                <TELEFON_PRIVAT>0521234567</TELEFON_PRIVAT>
                <TELEFON_GESCHAEFT>0529876543</TELEFON_GESCHAEFT>
            </TELEFON>
            <MOBILE>01781234567</MOBILE>
            <FAX>0526549873</FAX>
            <EMAIL>
                <EMAIL_PRIVAT>hans.meier@fantasia.de</EMAIL_PRIVAT>
                <EMAIL_GESCHAEFT>hans.meier@musterag.de</EMAIL_GESCHAEFT>
            </EMAIL>
            <HOMEPAGE>http://www.meierspage.de</HOMEPAGE>
        </KONTAKT>
    </PERSON>
    <PERSON KATEGORIE="Privat">
        <ANREDE TITEL="Herr"/>
        <VOLLER_NAME>
            <NAME>Elmer</NAME>
            <VORNAME>Rolf</VORNAME>
            <SPITZNAME>rolfi</SPITZNAME>
        </VOLLER_NAME>
        <GEBURTSTAG DATUM="28.3.1960"/>
        <BERUF BEZEICHNUNG="Abteilungsleiter"/>
        <ADRESSE>
            <ADRESSE_PRIVAT>
                <STRASSE>Dorfstrasse 23</STRASSE>
                <POSTLEITZAHL>56070</POSTLEITZAHL>
                <ORT>Koblenz</ORT>
                <REGION>Rheinland</REGION>
                <LAND>Deutschland</LAND>
            </ADRESSE_PRIVAT>
            <ADRESSE_GESCHAEFT>
                <FIRMA>Visita AG</FIRMA>
                <STRASSE>Alleestrasse 9</STRASSE>
                <POSTFACH>325</POSTFACH>
                <POSTLEITZAHL>56098</POSTLEITZAHL>
                <ORT>Koblenz</ORT>
                <REGION>Rheinland</REGION>
                <LAND>Deutschland</LAND>
                <HOMEPAGE>http://www.visita.de</HOMEPAGE>
            </ADRESSE_GESCHAEFT>
        </ADRESSE>
        <KONTAKT>
            <TELEFON>
                <TELEFON_PRIVAT>0523632854</TELEFON_PRIVAT>
                <TELEFON_GESCHAEFT>0526521771</TELEFON_GESCHAEFT>
            </TELEFON>
            <MOBILE>01793698547</MOBILE>
            <FAX>052652172</FAX>
            <EMAIL>
                <EMAIL_PRIVAT>rolf@gmx.com</EMAIL_PRIVAT>
                <EMAIL_GESCHAEFT>elmer.rolf@visita.de</EMAIL_GESCHAEFT>
            </EMAIL>
        </KONTAKT>
    </PERSON>
    <PERSON KATEGORIE="Privat">
        <ANREDE TITEL="Herr"/>
        <VOLLER_NAME>
            <NAME>Marks</NAME>
            <VORNAME>Alois</VORNAME>
            <SPITZNAME>wisi</SPITZNAME>
        </VOLLER_NAME>
        <GEBURTSTAG DATUM="22.12.1958"/>
        <BERUF BEZEICHNUNG="Versicherungs Agent"/>
        <ADRESSE>
            <ADRESSE_PRIVAT>
                <STRASSE>Untere Legi 5</STRASSE>
                <POSTLEITZAHL>65191</POSTLEITZAHL>
                <ORT>Wiesbaden</ORT>
                <REGION>Rheinhessen</REGION>
                <LAND>Deutschland</LAND>
            </ADRESSE_PRIVAT>
            <ADRESSE_GESCHAEFT>
                <FIRMA>Helsana Versicherungen AG</FIRMA>
                <STRASSE>Bahnhofstrasse 15</STRASSE>
                <POSTFACH>365</POSTFACH>
                <POSTLEITZAHL>65191</POSTLEITZAHL>
                <ORT>Wiesbaden</ORT>
                <REGION>Rheinhessen</REGION>
                <LAND>Deutschland</LAND>
                <HOMEPAGE>http://www.helsana.de</HOMEPAGE>
            </ADRESSE_GESCHAEFT>
        </ADRESSE>
        <KONTAKT>
            <TELEFON>
                <TELEFON_PRIVAT>0712689665</TELEFON_PRIVAT>
                <TELEFON_GESCHAEFT>0713265489</TELEFON_GESCHAEFT>
            </TELEFON>
            <MOBILE>01796942365</MOBILE>
            <FAX>01713265480</FAX>
            <EMAIL>
                <EMAIL_PRIVAT>wisi@gmx.de</EMAIL_PRIVAT>
                <EMAIL_GESCHAEFT>a.marks@helsana.de</EMAIL_GESCHAEFT>
            </EMAIL>
            <HOMEPAGE>http://www.wisimark.de</HOMEPAGE>
        </KONTAKT>
    </PERSON>
    <PERSON KATEGORIE="Geschäft">
        <ANREDE TITEL="Frau"/>
        <VOLLER_NAME>
            <NAME>Brunner</NAME>
            <VORNAME>Beatrix</VORNAME>
            <MITTELNAME>Katharina</MITTELNAME>
            <SPITZNAME>rina</SPITZNAME>
        </VOLLER_NAME>
        <GEBURTSTAG DATUM="15.1.1951"/>
        <BERUF BEZEICHNUNG="Kaufmännische Angestellte"/>
        <ADRESSE>
            <ADRESSE_PRIVAT>
                <STRASSE>Dreieck</STRASSE>
                <POSTLEITZAHL>65187</POSTLEITZAHL>
                <ORT>Idstein</ORT>
                <REGION>Rheinhessen</REGION>
                <LAND>Deutschland</LAND>
            </ADRESSE_PRIVAT>
            <ADRESSE_GESCHAEFT>
                <FIRMA>Spitex Verein</FIRMA>
                <STRASSE>Heimatstrasse 26</STRASSE>
                <POSTFACH>230</POSTFACH>
                <POSTLEITZAHL>79085</POSTLEITZAHL>
                <ORT>Freiburg</ORT>
                <REGION>Breisgau</REGION>
                <LAND>Deutschland</LAND>
                <HOMEPAGE>http://www.spitex-teufen.de</HOMEPAGE>
            </ADRESSE_GESCHAEFT>
        </ADRESSE>
        <KONTAKT>
            <TELEFON>
                <TELEFON_PRIVAT>0712253269</TELEFON_PRIVAT>
                <TELEFON_GESCHAEFT>01712253322</TELEFON_GESCHAEFT>
            </TELEFON>
            <EMAIL>
                <EMAIL_GESCHAEFT>teufen@spitex.de</EMAIL_GESCHAEFT>
            </EMAIL>
        </KONTAKT>
    </PERSON>
    <PERSON KATEGORIE="Privat">
        <ANREDE TITEL="Frau"/>
        <VOLLER_NAME>
            <NAME>Kamm</NAME>
            <VORNAME>Susanne</VORNAME>
            <SPITZNAME>susi</SPITZNAME>
        </VOLLER_NAME>
        <GEBURTSTAG DATUM="30.9.1970"/>
        <BERUF BEZEICHNUNG="Physiotherapeutin"/>
        <ADRESSE>
            <ADRESSE_PRIVAT>
                <STRASSE>Gartenweg</STRASSE>
                <POSTLEITZAHL>33790</POSTLEITZAHL>
                <ORT>Halle</ORT>
                <REGION>Westfalen</REGION>
                <LAND>Deutschland</LAND>
            </ADRESSE_PRIVAT>
            <ADRESSE_GESCHAEFT>
                <FIRMA>Physiotherapie Susanne Kamm</FIRMA>
                <STRASSE>Gartenweg</STRASSE>
                <POSTLEITZAHL>33790</POSTLEITZAHL>
                <ORT>Halle</ORT>
                <REGION>Westfalen</REGION>
                <LAND>Deutschland</LAND>
            </ADRESSE_GESCHAEFT>
        </ADRESSE>
        <KONTAKT>
            <TELEFON>
                <TELEFON_PRIVAT>0816495512</TELEFON_PRIVAT>
                <TELEFON_GESCHAEFT>0816495512</TELEFON_GESCHAEFT>
            </TELEFON>
            <MOBILE>01794508081</MOBILE>
            <FAX>0816495512</FAX>
            <EMAIL>
                <EMAIL_PRIVAT>susi70@hotmail.com</EMAIL_PRIVAT>
                <EMAIL_GESCHAEFT>s.kamm@physiotherapie-kamm.de</EMAIL_GESCHAEFT>
            </EMAIL>
            <HOMEPAGE>http://www.physiotherapie-kamm.de</HOMEPAGE>
        </KONTAKT>
    </PERSON>
    <PERSON KATEGORIE="Privat" PERSON_ID="6">
        <ANREDE TITEL="Herr"/>
        <VOLLER_NAME>
            <NAME>Jenny</NAME>
            <VORNAME>Heinrich</VORNAME>
            <MITTELNAME>Josef</MITTELNAME>
            <SPITZNAME>heiri</SPITZNAME>
        </VOLLER_NAME>
        <GEBURTSTAG DATUM="19.3.1933"/>
        <BERUF BEZEICHNUNG="Rentner"/>
        <ADRESSE>
            <ADRESSE_PRIVAT>
                <STRASSE>Tobel</STRASSE>
                <POSTLEITZAHL>33456</POSTLEITZAHL>
                <ORT>Bielefeld</ORT>
                <REGION>Westfalen</REGION>
                <LAND>Deutschland</LAND>
            </ADRESSE_PRIVAT>
        </ADRESSE>
        <KONTAKT>
            <TELEFON>
                <TELEFON_PRIVAT>0556436825</TELEFON_PRIVAT>
            </TELEFON>
            <EMAIL/>
        </KONTAKT>
    </PERSON>
    <PERSON KATEGORIE="Geschäft" PERSON_ID="7">
        <ANREDE TITEL="Herr"/>
        <VOLLER_NAME>
            <NAME>Pinkwasser</NAME>
            <VORNAME>Eduard</VORNAME>
            <SPITZNAME>edi</SPITZNAME>
        </VOLLER_NAME>
        <GEBURTSTAG DATUM="2.7.1940"/>
        <BERUF BEZEICHNUNG="Künstler"/>
        <ADRESSE>
            <ADRESSE_PRIVAT>
                <STRASSE>Sonnenallee 24</STRASSE>
                <POSTLEITZAHL>66623</POSTLEITZAHL>
                <ORT>Mainz</ORT>
                <REGION>Rheinhessen</REGION>
                <LAND>Deutschland</LAND>
            </ADRESSE_PRIVAT>
            <ADRESSE_GESCHAEFT>
                <FIRMA>Kunsthaus</FIRMA>
                <STRASSE>Sonnenallee 1</STRASSE>
                <POSTFACH>121</POSTFACH>
                <POSTLEITZAHL>67657</POSTLEITZAHL>
                <ORT>Rockenhausen</ORT>
                <REGION>Pfalz</REGION>
                <LAND>Deutschland</LAND>
                <HOMEPAGE>http://www.kunst-sevelen.de</HOMEPAGE>
            </ADRESSE_GESCHAEFT>
        </ADRESSE>
        <KONTAKT>
            <TELEFON>
                <TELEFON_PRIVAT>0813657895</TELEFON_PRIVAT>
                <TELEFON_GESCHAEFT>0813659874</TELEFON_GESCHAEFT>
            </TELEFON>
            <MOBILE>0178889689</MOBILE>
            <FAX>0813659870</FAX>
            <EMAIL>
                <EMAIL_PRIVAT>edi.art@bluemail.de</EMAIL_PRIVAT>
                <EMAIL_GESCHAEFT>eduard.pinkwasser@kunst-sevelen.de</EMAIL_GESCHAEFT>
            </EMAIL>
        </KONTAKT>
    </PERSON>
</ADRESSBUCH>
```

And here my xsl-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Adressbuch</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nr.</th>
                        <th>Anrede</th>
                        <th>Vorname</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Beruf</th>
                        <th>Tel. Privat</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/ADRESSBUCH/PERSON" />
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:number format="01" value="position()" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="/ADRESSBUCH/PERSON/ANREDE/@TITEL" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="/ADRESSBUCH/PERSON/VOLLER_NAME/VORNAME" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="/ADRESSBUCH/PERSON/VOLLER_NAME/NAME" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="/ADRESSBUCH/PERSON/BERUF/@BEZEICHNUNG" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="/ADRESSBUCH/PERSON/KONTAKT/TELEFON/TELEFON_PRIVAT" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this is my current output:

http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/unbenanntw1afuteozp.png

so it should get the next

the second will be looking like this:

02|Herr|Rolf|Elmer|Abteilungsleiter|0523632854

Comment: Please show the output you expect, and how it differs from what you get.

Comment: No need to say "I need help"... the fact you're asking a question is enough to tell us that

Comment: Also, do you really think you should be putting what looks like private information on a public website like this?

Comment: i edited my post with a picture of current looking, it isn't really private the adresses and names and all in there is random

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/ADRESSBUCH/PERSON/ANREDE/@TITEL" />
```

you are starting at the **root** of the XML input and getting the value of the **first** one of the selected nodes.

Since at this point you are already in the context of a `PERSON`<sup>1</sup>, you should be using the **relative** path from there:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ANREDE/@TITEL" />
```

and so on.

--

[1] For good measure, I would change:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="PERSON">
```

It will make no difference for as long as you are only using the two templates, but it will make a big difference if you ever find you need to add another one.